# matches between two arrays by position and value in php

Tags: php, arrays, compare, multiple-matches

Suppose I have two arrays with the same size.
for example:

```
array1 = array(5, 8, 6, 4);
array2 = array(5, 8, 7, 8);
```

and I need to know the matching between them in percents.
But the matching have to be by the position and value.
In this example, the matched ones are in `array[0]`, `array[1]` so I need to get 50% match.

And if I want to complicate it a little, then I can say if the difference between 
`array1[2]` and `array2[2]` is less than 1 (`7-6=1`), so the percentage amount would be 52%, because 6 and 7 are almost the same.

I need this because I want to compare between 2 users rate in my site the users can rate movies and I want to tell them that user1 rate have 60% matching to user 2 rate (in same movie).

Comment: If you consider the `6` and `7` _almost equal_, then the matching percentage should be `%75`, shouldn't be?!

Comment: Hello
you right but I don't want to calculate 75% because its not exactly equal 6 and 7 so I add less.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over both arrays and compare each pair of elements:

```
function compareArrays($arr1, $arr2, $diffThreshold) {
    # Assumption: both arrays are the same length.
    # If this isn't a valid assumption, take the length of the shortest
    $length = count($arr1);
    $ctr = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        if (abs($arr1[i] - $arr2[i]) <= $diffThreshold) {
            ++$ctr;
        }
    }
    return $ctr / $length;
}
```